# Python, CSV file only shows mm.ss and not hh.mm.ss

Tags: python, pandas, csv

In my csv file, the values for a column are 1/1/2022 12:34:16am. However, the value in the cell only shows 34:16.02 (minutes, seconds, and milliseconds).

I would like to convert this column to 1/1/2022 12:34:16am in datetime format so I can subtract another similar column to get the time difference.

I have tried to use strptime but it gives me an error that 'values must be in string format'. So I tried to convert the values to 'str' but that still does not work.

df['start'] = df['start'].astype("str")

df['start'] = datetime.strptime(df['start'], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

Anyone able to help? Thanks alot!

Comment: The code for year is `%Y` with a capital Y.  Is that what you have?  The problem here is that `datetime.strptime` requires a single string value, and you're trying to pass a pandas Series.  You can try using `apply` to do this.  If you give us some genuine sample data, we can try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
date_string = str(df['start'])
format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S%p'
df['start'] = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```